# Extract all "heading 1" from a Word doc

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I would like to extract all the text from a word document with "heading 1".
Currelenty I have the following code :

```
public static void Alina(String bestand, String kop) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(bestand);
    XWPFDocument xdoc=new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));

    List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphList = xdoc.getParagraphs();
    int aantal = 0;
    for (XWPFParagraph paragraph: paragraphList) {      
        if (paragraph.getStyle().equals(kop)) { 
            System.out.println("aantal keer door document :" +" " + aantal++);
            System.out.println(paragraph.getText());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Test");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this he only extract the first two "headings" and quits after hitting a white space or other text.
Has someone an idea to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

*ps. Kop means Heading in dutch.*

*edit : if I remove the break statement I get the same output and then he quits with a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your program finds a paragraph that does not have the "kop" style
`if(paragraph.getStyle().equals(kop))` then it will quit the `for loop`. I think you should remove the `break` and instead continue iterating through all paragraphs and check wether they have the necessary style.

check `kop != null` and handle it properly. If you made sure that kop is not null then do the following.

```
for (XWPFParagraph paragraph: paragraphList)
{     
  if(kop.equals(paragraph.getStyle()))
  { 
    System.out.println("aantal keer door document :" +" " + aantal++);
    System.out.println(paragraph.getText());
  }
  else
  {
    System.out.println("Test");
  }
```

}

Comment: If i remove the break and replace it with continue or just a print he still gets stuck with a null pointer.

Comment: You could try the following: Check `paragraph.getStyle != null` before checking wether it is equal to "kop"

Comment: Thanks `  if(paragraph.getStyle() !=null)` before checking the headings solves the problem.

Comment: Happy to help. I also edited my answer to a little bit more clean solution.